# Facing Problems compiling inuit.css in CodeKit

Tags: css, sass, codekit, inuit.css

I have 3 files in the `sass/` directory , they are

1. [style.scss](http://pastebin.com/Npsu5s71)
2. [_responsive.scss & _defaults.scss](http://pastebin.com/LXV5A0Vb)

And I also have a `vendor/` directory (outside the `sass\`) which contains the latest version of inuit.css from `https://github.com/csswizardry/inuit.css`.

When I am trying to compile the style.scss file in CodeKit I am getting the following error.

> Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "...uote:    \201C ": expected "}",
>   was "!global;"
>           on line 8 of /Users//Desktop/test/scss/../vendors/base/_quotes.scss
>           from line 162 of /Users//Desktop/test/scss/../vendors/_inuit.scss
>           from line 14 of /Users//Desktop/test/scss/style.scss   Use --trace for backtrace.

Comment: This question does not include the necessary detail inside the question itself, and uses a pasteboard instead. Accordingly I am voting as off topic for reasons of not being self-contained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the compiler code kit uses [doesn't support Sass 3.3 which introduced the `!global` flag](http://blog.sass-lang.com/posts/184094-sass-33-is-released). I would try using the Sass gem in the mean time.